# How to subtract all rows based on a column value and add them in extra column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a `ndarray` that contains 15 columns. The structure is like the bellow one

```
    col_1     col_2   col_3   col_4 Col_5
1   0.01      met_1   DT      2.3   0.78
2   0.01      met_1   DT_2    3.2   0.56
3   0.01      met_1   Lin     3.2   0.02
```

Now, I want to subtract `col_4` and `col_5` values for `DT` and `DT_2` from `Lin`. Finally, I want to add them in 2 new columns. The expected output is given below

```
    col_1     col_2   col_3   col_4 Col_5   del_col_4 del_col_5
1   0.01      met_1   DT      2.3   0.78    0.90    -0.76
2   0.01      met_1   DT_2    3.2   0.56    0.00    -0.54
3   0.01      met_1   Lin     3.2   0.02    0.00    0.00
```

Please, be noted, as I have 15 columns and say I want to only 10 columns (then I also have to add the subtraction result in extra 10 columns also). Could you tell me how can I do this?

Comment: I'm confused as to how you arrived at this particular data model. For however many unique values there may be for `col_2`, are there always exactly three values for `col_3` that are `DT`, `DT_2` and `Lin`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes they are exactly 3 values for `col_3`

Comment: Without knowing your exact needs, having three separate dataframes for `DT`, `DT_2`, and `Lin`, each indexed by what is currently `col_2`, might make this easier.

Comment: I am confused as well about the requirements what equation are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with

```
col = ['col_4','Col_5']
s = df[col].rsub(df.loc[df.col_3=='Lin',col].iloc[0],axis=1)
df = df.join(s.add_prefix('del_'))
df
Out[171]: 
   col_1  col_2 col_3  col_4  Col_5  del_col_4  del_Col_5
1   0.01  met_1    DT    2.3   0.78        0.9      -0.76
2   0.01  met_1  DT_2    3.2   0.56        0.0      -0.54
3   0.01  met_1   Lin    3.2   0.02        0.0       0.00
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df3=df.set_index('col_3')#Set index

df3.assign(del_col_4=df3.loc['Lin',  'col_4']-df3['col_4'],del_col_5=df3.loc['Lin',  'Col_5']-df3['Col_5']).reset_index()#slice index as you substract



col_3  col_1  col_2  col_4  Col_5  del_col_4  del_col_5
0    DT   0.01  met_1    2.3   0.78        0.9      -0.76
1  DT_2   0.01  met_1    3.2   0.56        0.0      -0.54
2   Lin   0.01  met_1    3.2   0.02        0.0       0.00
```